# MediaElement positioning issues : More or less 20 seconds variations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5, mediaelement

I'm looking for some help... I'm writing a WPF program that use a MediaElement.
I'm setting his position (as an example) to 01:02:15, but the video start playing at 01:02:03
If I'm setting position to 01:02:52 , it'll start playing at 01:02:43

As I see, positions can only be set to XX:XX:03 / XX:XX:23 / XX:XX:43

Have anyone face this problem before ? Or can give me a way to solve it ?

Thank you for all !

```
MyMediaElement.BeginInit();
MyMediaElement.Stop();
MyMediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(1, 25, 21);
MyMediaElement.Play();
MyMediaElement.EndInit();
```

Moreover, as I was debuging the program step by step, I saw that Position is cleany setted, but as I go trought the MyMediaElement.Play() method, Position is resetted to 01:23:00 ...

Comment: You clearly have an error in your code, but seeing as you didn't show us any, we'll never be able to find the problem.

Comment: How are you determining that the video starts at the wrong time... what are you reading those values from?

Comment: I got I timer that change a textBlock content every seconds with the MyMediaElement.Position value. And as I change the value by pressing buttons, the value appear to change to specials positions like I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED !**

The probleme came with the video I was trying to play and position.
Something wrong happenned with the video index, then I convert my video to mp4 in order to force reindexation.

Now it works well !!!